# System.Net.DnsPermission Error in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, ip, tcpclient

im doing client and server socket communication in c# but i got this error..

```
Error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.DnsPermission, 
       System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

what is the posibility for this error.. i run my application using another machine but it seems ok.. this error comes out when i use Windows SP3 with the latest .Net

i think the reason is im using a deprecated syntax in .Net

```
IPAddress IPAddress = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];
```

for getting the machine IPAddress.. is there another syntax for doing this? which is not deprecated..? i googled it and tried some blocks of code but IPAddress return IPV6 IP type.. :D

any help please.. :)

Comment: Note that pilling one random IP address will likely not work on servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this..

```
 using System.Net;

string host = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList[0].ToString());
```